# guardar checkbox en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una situación, quiero guardar una serie de respuestas que las tengo como opción de selección por medio de checkbox. ya tengo el código pero no me guarda los resultados.

esta es mi parte de opciones:

```html
<div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="COMO[]" value="1">01 Instrucción de Trabajo</label>
                            </div>
                           <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="COMO[]" value="2">02 Ayuda Visual</label>
                             </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="COMO[]" value="3">03 Formatos</label>
                               </div>
                             <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="COMO[]" value="4">04 Procedimientos</label>
                            </div>
                           <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="COMO[]" value="5">05 Alerta de Calidad</label>
                             </div>
```

y aquí es donde guardo los resultados.

```html
<?PHP
require_once 'conexion.php';
$_ID_COMO =  stripslashes ($_POST["ID_COMO"]);
$_COMO =  stripslashes ($_POST["COMO"]);

IF ($_ID_COMO) {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_COMO);$i++)    
        {     
            $query = "INSERT INTO metodologias (id_proceso,id_indicador,actividad)
            VALUES ('$_ID_PROCESO', '$_ID_COMO', '$_COMO'); ";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            if (!$result) die($conn->error);    
        }
}
```

Comment: La intencion es guardar todos los registros seleccionados?

Comment: si así es deseo guardar todos los registros seleccionados

Comment: amigo la verdad no lo creo posible, en la base de datos solo hay un campo, que es COMO, mas bien toca crear otra tabla que se llame respuestas y toca almacenarlas haí

Comment: estaba pensando en un ciclo y un array para ir guardando de un por uno, no importa que se repita el $_ID_PROCESO o el $_ID_COMO solo quiero que cambie el $_COMO